# Loop through multiple dimensions

Tags: algorithm, loops, delphi, iteration

I have a function `f` of several variables (for example of 3 variables `f(x,y,z)`). I would like to calculate the function results for a range of each variable and store them in a list. For 3 variables this could look like this:

```
procedure LoopOver3Dimensions;
type
  TListItem=record
    x, y, z: Real;
    CalculationResult: Real;
  end;
var
  List: TList<TListItem>;
  NewListItem: TListItem;
  i, j, k: Integer;
  x, y, z: Real;
  xStart, yStart, zStart: Real;
  xEnd, yEnd, zEnd: Real;
  NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension0: Integer;
  NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension1: Integer;
  NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension2: Integer;
begin
  //set xStart, xEnd, NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension0 etc here

  for i := 0 to NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension0 do
  begin
    x:=xStart+i*Abs(xEnd-xStart)/(NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension0-1);
    for j := 0 to NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension1 do
    begin
      y:=yStart+j*Abs(yEnd-yStart)/(NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension1-1);
      for k := 0 to NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension2 do
      begin
        z:=zStart+k*Abs(zEnd-zStart)/(NumberOfValuesToCalculateForDimension2-1);
        NewListItem.x:=x;
        NewListItem.y:=y;
        NewListItem.z:=z;
        NewListItem.CalculationResult:=DoCalculation(x, y, z);
        List.Add(NewListItem);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I can of course program this in the same way for more than 3 dimensions (e.g. 20 dimensions) but it will become very cumbersome and since everything is hard coded I cannot change the number of dimensions at runtime.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you are going to pass each argument in a separate parameter then you either need dynamic invocation of the function or hard coding. Better might be to pass the args in an array. If you really have 20 args then you aren't going to have time or memory to vary all of the args.

Comment: As @David said, use a (dynamic) array instead of x, y, z. And loop through the dimensions, instead of hardcoding the nested loops.

Comment: Of course, looping through the dimensions is a bit tricky too. You need an array of integer, length equal to dimension count. And an increment function. And a termination condition.

Comment: @David Could you please outline for us such an implementation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, in order to support an arbitrary number of arguments it is probably best to work with arrays of variable length rather than arguments. That is because the language does not have great support for variable length argument lists.

Once you package up all the arguments as an array, then you are faced with generating all the possible combinations. That is not a completely simple task. Rather than work with real values, I'm going to show you how to do this with each dimension being integer valued, in the range `0` to `N[i]-1`, where `i` is the dimension index. Once you can iterate over all such combinations, you can readily extend to generating your real values.

The basic concept is to maintain a current iteration value, which is incremented. The first dimension is the innermost of the loop. When it reaches its maximum value, it returns to zero and the next outer dimension is incremented. And so on. Here is some example code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure IterMultiDim(const N: array of Integer; const Proc: TProc<TArray<Integer>>);
var
  dim: Integer;
  Current: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Current, Length(N));
  while Current[high(N)]<N[high(N)] do begin
    Proc(Current);

    // increment state
    dim := 0;
    while dim<=high(N) do begin
      inc(Current[dim]);
      if Current[dim]=N[dim] then begin
        if dim<high(N) then begin
          Current[dim] := 0;
        end;
      end else begin
        break;
      end;
      inc(dim);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure WriteIntArray(Arr: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(Arr) do begin
    Write(Arr[i]);
    if i<high(Arr) then begin
      Write(', ');
    end;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  IterMultiDim([2, 3, 4], WriteIntArray);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output:**

```
0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
1, 1, 0
0, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
0, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
0, 2, 1
1, 2, 1
0, 0, 2
1, 0, 2
0, 1, 2
1, 1, 2
0, 2, 2
1, 2, 2
0, 0, 3
1, 0, 3
0, 1, 3
1, 1, 3
0, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

This technique could be wrapped up in a variety of ways. For instance, it could be encapsulated in a for/in enumerator which would enable greater readability.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by David's method I came up with another solution:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure IterMultiDim(const NumberOfCalculationsPerDimension: TArray<Integer>; const Proc: TProc<TArray<Integer>>);

  function ModInc(const MaxNumber: Integer; var AValue: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    Inc(AValue);
    if AValue>MaxNumber then
    begin
      AValue:=0;
      Result:=true; //carry
    end
    else
    begin
      Result:=false; //no carry
    end;
  end;

var
  NumberOfDimensions: Integer;
  CurrentIndices: TArray<Integer>;
  i, j: Integer;
  TotalNumberOfCalculations: Integer;
  Carry: Boolean;
begin
  NumberOfDimensions:=Length(NumberOfCalculationsPerDimension);
  SetLength(CurrentIndices, NumberOfDimensions);
  TotalNumberOfCalculations:=1;
  for i := 0 to NumberOfDimensions-1 do
  begin
    TotalNumberOfCalculations:=TotalNumberOfCalculations*NumberOfCalculationsPerDimension[i];
  end;

  for i := 0 to TotalNumberOfCalculations-1 do
  begin
    Proc(CurrentIndices);
    Carry:=true;
    for j := 0 to NumberOfDimensions-1 do
    begin
      if Carry then
      begin
        Carry:=ModInc(NumberOfCalculationsPerDimension[j]-1, CurrentIndices[j]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure WriteIntArray(Arr: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  S:='';
  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
  begin
    S:=S+Arr[i].ToString+'  ';
  end;
  Writeln(S);
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  IterMultiDim([3, 4, 2], WriteIntArray);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: There are many different ways you can write this code. You know how to solve your problem now. Aren't we done?

Comment: Yes, we are done. I just asked for comments in case one method would have advantages over another method. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a code review site. The obvious difference between the two implementations is that yours is more verbose.